# @MessageMapping with Grails spring-websocket plugin

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller, spring-websocket

I am a Grails newbie and working on getting WebSockets working in an application. I got most of it working except I couldn't figure out how to pass parameters to the methods annotated with @MessageMapping.

This works:

```
class MyController{
    @MessageMapping(value="/start")
    protected void startProcess(){ }
}
```

What I need something like this to work:

```
 @MessageMapping(value="/start/{file}")
 protected void startProcess(){ 
     String file = params.file
     //do somethig with the file...
 }
```

But it doesn't work. I have tried changing UrlMappings.groovy, @PathVariable. I am pretty sure I am missing something simple. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get something form the path use `@DestinationVariable` (see **20.4.4 Annotation Message Handling** in the [spring websocket](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) documentation).

Here is a working snippet (grails 2.4.3, based on the plugin example):

```
// Domain Class
class Foo {
    String name
    String desc
}

// controller method
@MessageMapping("/hello/{file}")
@SendTo("/topic/hello")
protected String hello(@DestinationVariable String file, @Payload Foo foo) {
    return "received: ${file} ${foo}"
}

// javascript
client.send("/app/hello/FILE", {}, JSON.stringify({
    'name': "foo",
    'desc': "a foo"
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. But I have noticed a bizarre behavior where it stops working sometimes and without any code changes starts working again.

Comment: hii.. how about multipe variable? `/hello/{file}/{mycode}` ??

Comment: @Martin Hauner hii.. how about multipe variable? /hello/{file}/{mycode} ??